# Whitespace in Jenkins global path variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have path name with whitespace and dash
Like this //sharename\TEST - PATH

Jenkins installed on windows server with git bash

If i add this path to global environment Jenkins cut end of path like this

```
//sharename\TEST
touch: setting times of '-': Invalid argument
PATH
```

I know i can escape it in bash using quotes.But I need to escape it every time.

Maybe exist better way to deal with it?

Comment: Did you try adding it as an `Environment variable`? (Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties)

Comment: @ArunKumarB yes. It's already in environment variable but because it contain space in path name, jenkis think it's a 3 path. 1st - //sharename/TEST. 2-nd - "-". 3rd - "PATH"

Comment: I just added an Environment variable with the same value. I'm able to echo the variable as expected in an `Execute shell` Build step.

Comment: I think I realized where you went wrong. Use "$temp" instead of $temp. This way your path won't be split up into 3 parts.

Comment: @stevemayster, you have 2 choices: doublequote variable every time or get rid of the spaces in your path; that's how the shell interpreter works. Personally, I'd go with gird rid of the spaces in your path.

Answer (score 1):

When using the variable, use it as "$var" instead of $var.

See below code for example:

```
var="abc - 123"

# creates three folders: abc,-,123
mkdir $var

# creates a single folder named: abc - 123
mkdir "$var"
```

Comment: Please,read my initial question carefully. " I know i can escape it in bash using quotes.But I need to escape it every time."

Comment: Quoting in shell programming is extremely important. When referencing a variable, it is generally advisable to enclose its name in double quotes. Leaving a variable unquoted in shells can be very dangerous especially when done in the wrong contexts. References: [1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes), [2](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html), [3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Comment: I recommend you to double quote the variable every time. If you're looking to avoid double quoting the variable, I do not have a workaround.